# Write specfic logs to syslog using logback in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, logback, syslog, spring-logback

I have a spring boot microservice application. logback.xml is configured to write the logs to a location on the server. In addition to this, I want to write logs from a particular java class to Syslog. I do not want logs from all other classes to be written to syslog but to a rolling file appender. Is there a way to configure this using logback.

below is my logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="logs"></property>
    <appender name="Console"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
   </appender>

   <appender name="RollingFile"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/data/storage/log/cms.log</file>
    <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- roll over daily and when the file reaches 10 MB, max of 7 days or 3GB threshold -->
        <fileNamePattern>/data/storage/log/cms.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.Logs.gz
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<appender name="SPECIFIC_CLASS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/sizeTimeOutputlogFile.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] %p %c{1.} [%t]- %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/sizeTimeOutputlogFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <!--Max Size of file to start Archive -->
            <maxFileSize>10KB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>

        <!-- Days till log history to keep -->
        <maxHistory>3</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<!--syslog appender-->
<appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
    <syslogHost>localhost</syslogHost>
    <facility>LOCAL0</facility>
    <port>514</port>
    <throwableExcluded>true</throwableExcluded>
    <suffixPattern>%thread: %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</suffixPattern>
</appender>

<!-- LOG everything at ERROR level -->
<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
</root>

<!-- LOG "com.myproject*" at ERROR level -->
<logger name="com.myproject" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.myproject.ActivityLogAspect" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="SPECIFIC_CLASS"/>
</logger>
</configuration>
```

From the above XML, SYSLOG and SPECIFIC_CLASS appenders are used to write logs from ActivityLogAspect class. When I run my application I see that only SPECIFIC_CLASS is working. I don't see any logs written to /var/log/messages. But if I add the SYSLOG appender along with the console appender, I see the messages written to /var/log/messages.

I do not want logs from all classes written to syslog but only from one particular class.

Please advise.